# Program to show hour, minutes and second

Tags: python

I have a simple program prints hour, minute and second. However, in line 6, the error message shows class Time() is not defined. I wonder why?

```
class Time(object):

    def print_time(time):
        print('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d' % (time.hour, time.minute, time.second))

    start = Time() #assign class Time to variable start

    start.hour = 9
    start.minute = 45
    start.second = 00

    Time.print_time(start) #classname.methodname(parameter)
```

Error message shows in line 6, class Time is not defined:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 6, in Time
builtins.NameError: name 'Time' is not defined
```

Comment: all the code starting from `start = Time()` is indented to the right, and is thus part of the `Time` class. So you're trying to init the class from it's def. indent everything to the left and it would work

Comment: There is no point to having a class here at all. Python is not Java.

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is wrong. It should be:

```
class Time(object):

    def print_time(time):
        print('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d' % (time.hour, time.minute, time.second))

start = Time() #assign class Time to variable start

start.hour = 9
start.minute = 45
start.second = 00

Time.print_time(start) #classname.methodname(parameter)
```

Otherwise the code to define `start` is executed *while* defining the `Time` class itself.

Comment: It's a bit confusing if the OP really wants this as a classmethod... Otherwise, I'd suggest they rename `time` to `self` (to stick with naming conventions for bound methods) and call `start.print_time()` instead... (wouldn't hurt to have an `__init__` there either :))

Answer (score 0):

While others pointed out to your problem, I want to advise you to use [`Arrow`](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) and simply:

```
arrow.utcnow().format('HH:mm:ss')
```

<sup>You need to `pip install arrow` before importing it</sup>